# Changing string format (python)

Tags: python, string

I want to change the string `'datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 15, 12, 59)'` into the format `'2018-04-15T12:59'`.

I created a function that looks like:

```
def changeDateFormat(date):
    newDate = []
    for i in date.split('datetime')[2].split(','):
        newDate.append(re.sub('[() ]', '', i))
    newStr = newDate[0] + '-0' + newDate[1] + '-' + newDate[2] + 'T' + newDate[3] + ':' + newDate[4]
    return newStr
```

And it works.

However, I also want it to handle the case where if each unit is less than 10, I want to add a `'0'`. Right now it just adds a `'0'` regardless.

I can do it in a very inefficient way, but I wonder how I can do it in a smart way.

Comment: The nicer solution is avoiding ending up with the `repr` of a datetime object in the first place.

Comment: I'm really with @miradulo on this. Must you work with a `repr`-string? Why can't you have accesses to the actually `datetime` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you use the string representation of a datetime object but `eval` is your friend:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> eval('datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 15, 12, 59)').isoformat()
'2018-04-15T12:59:00'
```

`eval` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: _"but eval is your friend"_ - Eh, I'd really advise not to use `eval` here - or anywhere. There's almost always a better way then using `eval`. It may be tempting to use `eval`, but I'd find something different instead. Please see [_Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?
_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're trying to avoid using the `datetime` object, because it seems obviously confusing otherwise.

> I can do it in a very inefficient way

You are actually not very far away, just one line.

```
def changeDateFormat(date):
    newDate = []
    for i in date.split('datetime')[2].split(','):
        newDate.append(re.sub('[() ]', '', i))

    pad = '-0' if newDate[1] < 10 else '-'
    newStr = newDate[0] + pad + newDate[1] + '-' + newDate[2] + 'T' + newDate[3] + ':' + newDate[4]
    return newStr
```

I'm afraid there isn't any smarter way if you're not using the `datetime` object.

Comment: Not that I really think the OP should be doing it this way (he really should try to get the actually `datetime` object and not the `repr`), but you could use `re.findall` to grab the digits and avoid all that substitution stuff with `re.sub`.

Answer (score 1):

datetime.strftime and eval would be perfect here.

```
import datetime
# use eval to execute the string like a a command
dt = eval('datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 15, 12, 59)')

formatted_date = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

> output: '2018-04-15T12:59'

Reference: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: I know it's tempting, but it really is best to avoid using `eval`. Please see [_Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Comment: Well of course it would be a case by case scenario on whether eval is bad or not. In OP's case I don't see how using `eval` is bad. However, I understand the debate and why it should generally be avoided.